# How to convert a CodeSandbox proyecto into a React Production App?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, compilation, codesandbox

I'm having a little problem with React App, see. My computer is a bullshit and I program in CodeSandbox. a week ago I have finished my React App that I was made in CodeSandbox and for upload it in my host I've downloaded the proyect to my pc and I open the command prompt for make a production build. I've used npm install for every dependencies and those things, ffter an hour, or so, my build was supposed to be ready so I used static-server to open it on my local internet, total. That when I was going to upload it to the host it did not work, I do not know why, but it goes blank.

Please I need help because I'm making a web for educational purposes :(

Thanks my web: http://eskoni.ezyro.com/d/ and sorry for that long history XD

Comment: Looks like some of your files were not uploaded properly. For example your index.html loads a `<script src="/static/js/main.ecc7ddfd.chunk.js"></script>` but when I go to http://eskoni.ezyro.com/static/js/1.e2e3f771.chunk.js, it redirects to a 404 page of your host.

Comment: Ohh lol, why my html has that files, in http://eskoni.ezyro.com/d/static/ I have my files and I watched that the index.html src is diferent. Why this?

Comment: Hmm bro, thats be crazy, the hosting are redirecting to the root of the host and not to the "d/static" hmm but I have fixed it only passing the files to the root